# Are there drawbacks to extending Azure Mobile Services(.net backend) to a more complex business app rather than just CRUD?

Tags: .net, rest, azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-cloud-services

I'm having information overload from researching this, so I just need to hear someone Else's experience...

My (oversimplified) problem is this: I need to create a Web API that both mobile and web clients can access, but will include business logic, not just basic CRUD operations, and lastly it needs to be secure.

We're going with Azure and we'd rather stay on the .NET end of things, so no JavaScript Backend.

From the sounds of it, my options Cloud Services or Mobile Services. **I'm leaning toward Mobile Services because it seems that integration with ACS is much much easier than with Cloud Services.** However most posts online that I've read have very basic Mobile Service samples (and most are for JavaScript) that make me think Mobile Services is just not fit for a bigger application.

**Are there any drawbacks to extending a Mobile Svc to multiple controllers that hand off requests a more complex BI engine rather than just letting the request through and updating the database?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're looking for in terms of drawbacks - that sounds a bit subjective. And... you actually asked a different question than your title suggests. I'm ignoring the title, since otherwise the question would be closed as 'too broad' or 'opinion-based.' ***(hint: You should probably change your title to match your question about going beyond CRUD operations in mobile services).***

From an objective standpoint: Out of the box, Mobile Services has CRUD operations built-in, along with language-specific client-side support for these operations. To go beyond that, uou need to look at Mobile Services' Custom API ability, which allows you to build whatever backend handling you need. You can then use whatever database engine you want (as long as you have the proper drivers), work with any resources you want (such as queues and service bus), etc.

Comment: Thanks! I figured as much but was reading so much stuff with really simple CRUD stuff that I thought maybe it was a bad idea going that direction, but your confirmation helps ease my mind!